# updating entity using Core Data sending message to deallocated instance

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I am experiencing a most weird error trying to update values on entities. I a new to core data, so might be something stupid...

here is my update code:

```
-(BOOL)trataTarefa:(TarefaMap*) mapa{

NSFetchRequest *request =[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[DataSource sharedManager]managedObjectContext];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Tarefa" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[request setEntity:entity];
NSPredicate *predicate;
predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"cd_tarefa == %@ AND cd_instalacao contains[cd] %@ ", mapa.cd_tarefa, mapa.cd_instalacao];
[request setPredicate:predicate];

NSError *error=nil;
NSArray *result = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
[request release];
NSLog(@"result=%d",[result count]);

if([result count]==1){
    if (mapa.tp_operacao ==3){

        Tarefa* tarefa = [result objectAtIndex:0];
        [tarefa setTp_operacao:[NSNumber numberWithInt:3]]; 


        NSLog(@"Tarefa=%@", tarefa);
        NSError* saveError=nil;
        if (![context save:&saveError]) {
            NSLog(@"Saving changes to book book two failed: %@", saveError);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Teoricamente gravou...") ;   

        }            
    }
}    
return YES;
```

}

the code works, it saves the entries, but it returns a *** -[CFNumber release]: message sent to deallocated instance #####
tracing it with shell malloc_history, I get:

```
Date/Time:       2011-03-24 14:12:01.988 -0300
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.6.6 (10J567)
Report Version:  7

ALLOC 0x6603f60-0x6603f6f [size=16]: thread_a052f540 |start | main | UIApplicationMain |
-[UIApplication _run] | CFRunLoopRunInMode | CFRunLoopRunSpecific | __CFRunLoopRun |  
 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 | __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ | 
 PurpleEventCallback | _UIApplicationHandleEvent | -[UIApplication sendEvent:] 
| -  [UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] | -[UIApplication
 _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] | -
[UIApplication _createStatusBarWithRequestedStyle:orientation:hidden:] | -[UIStatusBar
requestStyle:animated:] | -[UIStatusBar requestStyle:animationParameters:] | -  
[UIStatusBarWindow setCornerStyle:] | -[UIImageView initWithImage:] | -[UIImageView 
setImage:] | -[UIImageView(UIImageViewInternal) _updateState] | -
[UIImageView(UIImageViewInternal) _canDrawContent] | -[UIView(Rendering) contentMode] |
+[NSNumber numberWithInt:] | -[NSPlaceholderNumber initWithInt:] | CFNumberCreate |
_CFRuntimeCreateInstance | malloc_zone_malloc 

Binary Images:
0x1000 -    0x5cff3 +Nonononono (??? - ???) <C4B33680-F374-3E37-9C91-6DEDE06C4701> 
 /Users/marsson/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.1/Applications/B13321A3-
 1E73-4DC0-8E37-E2E56116ECEA/Nonononoo.app/Nnonononononono
```

What I can take from that log, is that the object is not really deallocated...
I already tried to update the object with setValue:forKey with the same result... if I comment the line on the update, the code runs, but of course the object is not updated.
Anyone had a similar problem??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Were in the code above do you get the error. Does it happen during saving, immediately after a successful save or at some other point. The malloc trace has nothing to do with Core Data but rather with the creation of the app's status bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it was a stupid thread problem... I was trying to update the ManagedContext from an background thread, and it was sometimes crashing the application. Once I used a different managed context, and used notification center to sync the context, everything went smooth. Thanks everyone for the suggestions...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a problem with [tarefa setTp_operacao:].  Can you post the code to the Tarefa class?  The NSNumber you create is autoreleased, so if Tarefa is not retaining it when setTP_operacao is run, you will be accessing a deallocated object after the autorelease pool releases (probably at the end of the current UI event).